# ASP .NET MVC list passed in ViewBag is displaying only the first record multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework, viewbag

I am collecting items that have the same IDs from a table called ProductManager, but when I pass the list into a ViewBag and I display it on the View it only displays the first record multiple times.
I have try multiple way to select records that have the same ID in the controller but the result is still the same, that's make me believe that the problem comes from the View.
NB: Inside the database my records are not the same.

This is my current Controller:

```
            public ReportController(Db_Context context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }
            // GET: ReportController
            public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string id)
            {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var itemlist = await _context.ProductManager
            .Where(x => x.TokenId == id).ToListAsync();

            var noteSelected = await _context.DeliveryNote.FindAsync(id);
            ViewBag.items = itemlist;
                return View(noteSelected);
            }
```

This is my View:

```
@model DeliveryNote3.Models.DeliveryNote

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
@{int count = 1;}
  <div class="container2">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="th1">
                    </th>
                    <th class="th1">Items</th>
                    <th class="th1"></th>
                    <th class="th1">Quantités</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:10%">N°</th>
                    <th style="width:20%">Name</th>
                    <th style="width:50%">Description</th>
                    <th style="width:10%">Envoyées</th>
                    <th style="width:10%">Reçue</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="items-list">
                @foreach (ProductManager product in ViewBag.items)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@count</td>
                        <td>@product.ProductName</td>
                        <td>@product.ProductDescription</td>
                        <td>@product.ProductQuantity</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    count++;
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Here is the result:
[image]
Here is the records that should be displayed:
[image]

Comment: I haven't worked with ASP.NET for a long time now but AFAIK you should use IEnumerable class to enumerate through your collection/array

`@model IEnumerable<ProductManager>`

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in your Index method on `ViewBag.items = itemlist;` what items are in the itemlist? Are they the 3 unique product managers you expect, or 3 instances of the same record?

Comment: Generally I use models for MVC views rather than ViewBag/Data, you may need to strongly type collections to get them out reliably. If the data going into the ViewBag looks correct then you could try this in your view: `@foreach (ProductManager product in ((List<ProductManager>)ViewBag.items))`

Comment: When I put a breakpoint on ViewBag.items = itemlist; I can only see the first record, which means that I is not collecting all records with the same ID but only the first one

Comment: @YannickMakwenge It could be this issue because of which you are getting multiple items on your `View`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71427159/asp-net-mvc-5-c-sharp-foreach-loop-repeats-same-data

Comment: @RahulSharma You could be right since I don't have a primery key for Product manager, I will try to rebuild the table with a primary key and to keep my TokenId beside

Comment: Problem Solved, I was having this issue because my table did not have a primary key and EF identifies records using primary keys, so I created a column "Id" to use as primery key and I kept "TokenId" as reference. Thanks @RahulSharma